# current working directory is not a cordova-based project

Tags: android, cordova

Всем доброго времени суток! Пытаюсь работать с cordova через коммандную строкую вылезает такая ошибка. проект был успешно создан и cordova загружена. СО WIndows 10. у кого-то было?

Answer (score 1):

нужно было войти в пройект с помощью строки 
cd projectName
После этого добавлять платформу